# How to use jQuery to generate ages for <select> <options> CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Someone mentioned that you can use jQuery to generate ages for dropdown CSS. Can someone explain to me how that works. I also want to connect the jQuery to a CSS class

Comment: what do you mean by generating ages?

Comment: Can you explain Clearly ?

Comment: So if you have an answer, share the solution or delete an answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="Year" class="bdayyear">
    <option value="year">Year</option>
    <script language="javascript">
                for (var i = 1960; i < 2010; i ++) {
                    document.write("<option value=\"" + i + "\">" + i + "</option>\n");
                }
            </script>
    </select>
```

Sorry guys, I'm new to Stack over flow. But that's the answer. Enjoy!